# Extract confidence intervals from an nlmrt object

Tags: r, confidence-interval, nls, non-linear-regression

**NOTE**: there are 2 huge objects in this question, in order to make the question reproducible. You don't need to read the declaration of the objects line by line to answer the question: their declaration (obtained with `dump("x", file=stdout())` ) is only provided so that you can load the objects in your R environment and inspect them.

I have this object of class `"nlmrt"` (sorry, it's huge):

```
library(nlmrt)
results.nlmrt <-
structure(list(resid = c(-1.873797, -1.082639, -3.128738, -2.065225, 
10.036262, 9.038775, -0.557938, -0.0227550000000001, -1.541254, 
-0.617675999999999, -2.193645, -0.939828000000002, 0.81962, 0.856692, 
1.588436, 1.7647, -10.546283, 3.360661, -0.835847, -0.578092, 
-1.147379, -0.930261999999999, -1.252843, -2.1055, 1.347841, 
-0.329777, -4.147924, -3.676401, 5.342006, 5.818819, -0.225925, 
-0.058781999999999, 0.334197, 0.4505, 1.017727, 0.669381000000001, 
1.884993, 1.454699, 1.67084, 1.755269, -0.471676, -0.524057, 
-3.373085, -3.278019, -6.219445, -7.161793, -10.737809, -8.693415, 
-2.840445, -3.136342, -3.662787, -5.37458, 5.945885, 5.213688, 
-3.884115, -3.71474, -6.818322, -6.348495, -11.975686, -8.800068, 
5.806859, 5.054232, -2.531185, -2.013974, -3.746896, -3.020429, 
-1.304244, -1.113971, -2.777007, -2.837965, -5.07189, -5.658287, 
-1.151053, -0.947455, -2.547545, -2.744747, 0.790208, 0.546432, 
1.517014, 1.102288, 1.249165, 1.011463, 0.126482000000003, 0.136798000000002, 
0.28296, 0.225576, -0.284154, -0.15046, 1.068714, 0.816097, 1.561979, 
1.208949, -3.193332, -2.120788, -2.501207, -1.75678, -2.265861, 
-1.396114, 6.420019, 7.175985, 3.453049, 4.296639, 1.910447, 
2.479853, 1.147497, 1.288324, 5.996762, 5.92161, 3.146104, 3.158998, 
1.668787, 1.702539, 2.113205, 1.845771, 1.327114, 1.440344, 0.855292, 
7.73017, 7.746381, 4.152009, 4.183986, 2.682163, 2.957113, 2.189862, 
2.137862, 6.977142, 6.592122, 1.520254, 1.794167, 10.447364, 
3.10818, 5.574112, 5.101422, 1.407211, 1.852486, -0.278430999999999, 
-0.0941270000000003, -1.314603, -1.201795, 0.934806999999999, 
1.114106, 0.63108, 0.722106, -5.211555, -5.645131, 0.864519, 
0.7813243, 0.390436, 0.024733, -1.043325, -2.48613, -1.85254, 
-2.045719, -2.385649, -2.223719, -3.935888, -2.720326, -2.658094, 
-1.243398, -1.903095, -0.581753, -2.544048, -4.201287, -4.221324, 
-4.733332, -3.42192, -7.584243, -5.434314, -2.059307, -1.756377, 
-4.803778, -0.601198, -2.301358, -3.166855, -0.628322000000001, 
-2.278394, -2.974249, -1.86614, -1.244455, -0.89637, -5.43132, 
-5.769175, -8.980463, -10.269705, -1.49086, -1.077036, -2.536101, 
-2.301336, -6.2600988, -5.661762, -0.400368, -0.43933, -1.538335, 
-2.086426, -5.888978, -6.759651, -0.428561, -0.977354, -3.140401, 
-3.14137, -1.224751, -1.418533, -5.543907, -6.148431, -3.763996, 
-3.526406, -4.757332, -4.234969, -2.743054, -2.236952, -0.819221, 
-0.932174), jacobian = structure(c(-3.17994601613073, -3.17994601613073, 
0, -15.8997300798063, 0, -15.8997300798063, -1.58997300806537, 
-1.58997300806537, -3.17994601584829, -3.17994601584829, 0, 0, 
1.58997300792415, 1.58997300799476, 3.17994601584829, 3.17994601613073, 
15.8997300798063, 0, -1.58997300792415, -1.58997300806537, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -15.8997300792415, -15.8997300792415, 3.17994601613073, 
4.76991902377244, 3.17994601598951, 1.58997300792415, -4.76991902405488, 
-4.76991902405488, -3.17994601584829, -3.17994601598951, 0, 0, 
-15.8997300798063, 0, 0, 0, -1.58997300792415, -1.58997300792415, 
-1.58997300806537, -1.58997300792415, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.58997300806537, 
-3.17994601598951, -15.8997300798063, -15.8997300798063, 1.58997300792415, 
1.58997300792415, -1.58997300806537, -3.17994601598951, 0, 0, 
-15.8997300798063, 0, 1.58997300792415, 3.17994601584829, -1.58997300806537, 
-1.58997300792415, 0, -15.8997300798063, 0, -1.58997300792415, 
-1.58997300792415, -1.58997300806537, -15.8997300798063, 0, -1.58997300799476, 
-1.58997300799476, -3.17994601598951, -3.17994601598951, 0, 0, 
1.58997300792415, 1.58997300806537, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58997300799476, 
1.58997300799476, 1.58997300799476, 0, 1.58997300799476, 0, 1.58997300792415, 
3.17994601598951, -15.8997300798063, 0, -4.76991902391366, -3.17994601598951, 
0, -15.8997300798063, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.58997300792415, -3.17994601584829, 
-1.58997300792415, -1.58997300799476, 0, 0, -3.17994601584829, 
-1.58997300792415, -1.58997300792415, -1.58997300792415, 0, 0, 
3.17994601598951, 1.58997300792415, 1.58997300799476, -15.8997300798063, 
0, -3.17994601584829, -3.17994601613073, 0, 0, -1.58997300792415, 
-1.58997300792415, 0, -15.8997300798063, -1.58997300806537, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58997300799476, 1.58997300799476, 3.17994601613073, 
3.17994601584829, 15.8997300798063, 0, 3.17994601598951, 1.58997300792415, 
1.58997300799476, 1.58997300799476, 0, -1.58997300792415, 0.158997300803006, 
0.174897030874481, 0.476991902391366, 0.476991902409018, 1.58997300799476, 
1.58997300806537, -0.158997300785354, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
-1.58997300806537, 0, 0.635989203141415, 0.794986504103292, 1.11298110560339, 
0, 0, -1.58997300806537, 0.635989203212024, 0, 0.635989203282633, 
0.794986503979726, 0, 0, -4.76991902391366, -4.76991902391366, 
0, -1.58997300792415, -1.58997300806537, 0, -1.58997300806537, 
-1.58997300792415, 0, 0, 0.476991902391366, 0.476991902391366, 
0.794986503962074, 0.794986503962074, 1.81256922910131, 2.06696491038612, 
-1.58997300799476, -1.58997300799476, -1.58997300806537, -1.58997300806537, 
-1.58997300792415, 0, -6.35989203197903, -6.35989203197903, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58997300792415, 1.58997300792415, 1.58997300792415, 
1.58997300806537, 0.158997300803006, 0.476991902391366, -13.7270193342762, 
-12.2017949638612, -15.2522437046911, -30.5044874093822, -30.5044874093822, 
-45.7567311146151, -6.10089748193062, -7.62612185234555, -13.7270193340052, 
-13.7270193342762, -30.5044874099241, -30.5044874093822, 6.10089748193062, 
6.10089748193062, 12.2017949635903, 13.7270193342762, 45.7567311140733, 
30.5044874093822, -6.10089748193062, -6.10089748193062, -15.2522437046911, 
-15.252243704962, -30.5044874093822, -30.5044874099241, -45.7567311135314, 
-45.7567311135314, 13.7270193342762, 15.2522437046911, 9.15134622289594, 
9.15134622289594, -18.3026924457919, -18.3026924457919, -10.6765705931754, 
-12.2017949637258, -45.7567311140733, 1082.90930303524, -30.5044874093822, 
-15.2522437046911, -15.2522437046911, -15.2522437046911, -7.62612185234555, 
-6.10089748179516, -7.62612185234555, -7.62612185234555, -15.2522437046911, 
-15.2522437046911, -30.5044874093822, -30.5044874099241, -7.62612185234555, 
-7.62612185234555, -15.2522437046911, -15.2522437046911, 7.62612185234555, 
6.10089748193062, -7.62612185248101, -7.62612185234555, -15.2522437046911, 
-15.2522437046911, -30.5044874093822, -15.252243705233, 6.10089748193062, 
7.62612185234555, -7.62612185234555, -7.62612185234555, -15.2522437046911, 
-30.5044874093822, -4.57567311144797, -4.57567311138023, -7.62612185234555, 
-7.62612185234555, -30.5044874093822, -15.2522437046911, -4.57567311144797, 
-4.57567311138023, -10.6765705933109, -9.15134622289594, 3.05044874096531, 
3.05044874096531, 7.62612185234555, 7.62612185234555, 15.2522437046911, 
15.2522437046911, 30.5044874093822, 30.5044874093822, 4.57567311144797, 
4.57567311138023, 4.57567311144797, 4.57567311144797, 4.57567311144797, 
3.05044874096531, 7.62612185234555, 10.6765705933109, -30.5044874093822, 
-30.5044874096531, -13.7270193342762, -13.7270193342762, -30.5044874093822, 
-30.5044874093822, -30.5044874093822, -30.5044874093822, -15.2522437046911, 
-15.2522437046911, -10.6765705931754, -10.6765705931754, -6.10089748179516, 
-4.57567311138023, -15.2522437046911, -15.2522437046911, -12.2017949635903, 
-10.6765705931754, -6.10089748193062, -6.10089748193062, 15.252243704962, 
15.2522437046911, 10.6765705933109, 9.15134622289594, 6.10089748193062, 
-30.5044874093822, -15.2522437046911, -10.6765705931754, -10.6765705934463, 
-4.57567311138023, -4.5756731115157, -4.57567311138023, -6.10089748179516, 
-30.5044874093822, -30.5044874096531, -6.10089748193062, -4.57567311138023, 
-15.2522437046911, -15.2522437046911, -15.2522437046911, -30.5044874096531, 
6.10089748186289, 4.57567311144797, 13.7270193342762, 13.7270193342762, 
30.5044874096531, 15.2522437046911, 10.6765705933109, 10.6765705933109, 
4.57567311144797, 6.10089748193062, -1.52522437055039, -4.5756731115157, 
0.457567311138023, 0.610089748189676, 1.98279168160375, 1.83026924456903, 
6.10089748193062, 6.10089748193062, -0.305044874069438, 0, -1.52522437041492, 
-1.52522437048266, -1.52522437048266, 0, -1.52522437048266, 0, 
0, -3.05044874096531, -1.52522437048266, 2.44035899269097, 2.59288142989502, 
4.11810580030994, 4.57567311138023, -4.57567311138023, -6.10089748193062, 
2.13531411868927, 1.52522437048266, 2.59288142989502, 2.89792630389673, 
0, 1.52522437048266, -21.3531411866217, -19.8279168160713, -1.52522437041492, 
-4.57567311138023, -7.62612185234555, -3.05044874089758, -7.62612185234555, 
-6.10089748179516, 0, -15.2522437046911, 1.52522437048266, 1.67774680755124, 
2.59288142975955, 2.59288142975955, 6.68048274270997, 7.47359941527696, 
-4.57567311138023, -4.57567311138023, -4.57567311138023, -4.57567311138023, 
-4.57567311138023, -4.57567311138023, -25.9288142978665, -25.9288142981374, 
0, -1.52522437055039, 0, -1.52522437048266, -3.05044874096531, 
-3.05044874110078, 1.52522437048266, 3.05044874096531, 4.5756731115157, 
4.57567311138023, 7.62612185234555, 9.15134622289594, 0.762612185241328, 
1.22017949637935), .Dim = c(212L, 2L)), feval = 31, jeval = 14, 
    coefficients = structure(c(0.628931491356317, -0.655631241727379
    ), .Names = c("ffactor_Ns", "ffactor_Ms")), ssquares = 3107.43103734174, 
    lower = c(-1, -1), upper = c(1, 1), maskidx = NULL), .Names = c("resid", 
"jacobian", "feval", "jeval", "coefficients", "ssquares", "lower", 
"upper", "maskidx"), class = "nlmrt")
```

I need to extract confidence intervals for the two parameters `ffactor_Ns` and `ffactor_Ms`. If I `print` the object I can see the standard error on screen, which can be used to compute confidence intervals:

```
> print(results.nlmrt)
nlmrt class object: x 
residual sumsquares =  3107.4  on  212 observations
    after  14    Jacobian and  31 function evaluations
  name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      gradient    JSingval   
ffactor_Ns      0.628931       0.05673      11.09          0       101.8        1106  
ffactor_Ms     -0.655631      0.003512     -186.7          0       913.1        67.8
```

However, I need the confidence intervals to be computed automatically: I cannot count on someone being in front of the screen each time I run the code. With your help, [I was able to convert the object to an object of class `"nls"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319141/what-im-doing-wrong-here-when-trying-to-convert-an-nlmrt-object-to-an-nls-objec), which has a `confint` method:

```
library(nls2)
nls_object <-
structure(list(m = structure(list(resid = function () 
resid, fitted = function () 
rhs, formula = function () 
form, deviance = function () 
dev, lhs = function () 
lhs, gradient = function () 
.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient"), conv = function () 
{
    if (npar == 0) 
        return(0)
    rr <- qr.qty(QR, resid)
    sqrt(sum(rr[1L:npar]^2)/sum(rr[-(1L:npar)]^2))
}, incr = function () 
qr.coef(QR, resid), setVarying = function (vary = rep_len(TRUE, 
    length(useParams))) 
{
    assign("useParams", if (is.character(vary)) {
        temp <- logical(length(useParams))
        temp[unlist(ind[vary])] <- TRUE
        temp
    }
    else if (is.logical(vary) && length(vary) != length(useParams)) 
        stop("setVarying : 'vary' length must match length of parameters")
    else {
        vary
    }, envir = thisEnv)
    gradCall[[length(gradCall) - 1L]] <<- useParams
    if (all(useParams)) {
        assign("setPars", setPars.noVarying, envir = thisEnv)
        assign("getPars", getPars.noVarying, envir = thisEnv)
        assign("getRHS", getRHS.noVarying, envir = thisEnv)
        assign("npar", length(useParams), envir = thisEnv)
    }
    else {
        assign("setPars", setPars.varying, envir = thisEnv)
        assign("getPars", getPars.varying, envir = thisEnv)
        assign("getRHS", getRHS.varying, envir = thisEnv)
        assign("npar", length(seq_along(useParams)[useParams]), 
            envir = thisEnv)
    }
}, setPars = function (newPars) 
{
    setPars(newPars)
    assign("resid", .swts * (lhs - assign("rhs", getRHS(), envir = thisEnv)), 
        envir = thisEnv)
    assign("dev", sum(resid^2), envir = thisEnv)
    assign("QR", qr(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")), envir = thisEnv)
    return(QR$rank < min(dim(QR$qr)))
}, getPars = function () 
getPars(), getAllPars = function () 
getPars(), getEnv = function () 
env, trace = function () 
{
    cat(format(dev), ": ", format(getPars()))
    cat("\n")
}, Rmat = function () 
qr.R(QR), predict = function (newdata = list(), qr = FALSE) 
eval(form[[3L]], as.list(newdata), env)), .Names = c("resid", 
"fitted", "formula", "deviance", "lhs", "gradient", "conv", "incr", 
"setVarying", "setPars", "getPars", "getAllPars", "getEnv", "trace", 
"Rmat", "predict"), class = "nlsModel"), call = quote(nls2(formula = model_string, 
    start = coef(results.nlmrt), algorithm = "brute")), convInfo = structure(list(
    isConv = TRUE, finIter = 2L, finTol = NA), .Names = c("isConv", 
"finIter", "finTol"))), .Names = c("m", "call", "convInfo"), class = "nls")
```

Unfortunately, the `confint` method is not working!

```
> confint(nls_object)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in chol2inv(object$m$Rmat()) : 
  element (2, 2) is zero, so the inverse cannot be computed
```

I have no idea what this `$m$Rmat` method is supposed to do, but it seems to compute some matrix with only one non-zero element:

```
> nls_object$m$Rmat()
        [,1] [,2]
[1,] -1028.7    0
[2,]     0.0    0
```

I'm at the end of my rope. The SE (and thus the confidence interval) must be buried somewhere inside `results.nlrmt`, otherwise `print` couldn't show it. Why is so darn difficult to extract it?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the broom package which is designed to tidy the results of models

Comment: Maybe the print method is computing it? Check the source code.

Comment: @Roland  looks like `print` is bytecode, so I can't see the source:`function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
<bytecode: 0x2d06838>
<environment: namespace:base>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19226817/1412059

Comment: @Roland thanks! Solved it. I will answer my question so that it can help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Roland's comment, I found out that the solution is actually very simple. To extract standard errors, *t*-statistics or *p*-values from an object of class `"nlmrt"`, just do the following:

```
library(nlmrt)
goofy <- summary(results.nlmrt)
#standard errors
goofy$SEs
#t-statistics
goofy$tstat
#p-values
goofy$pval
```

Of course, `summary(results.nlmrt)` was one of the first things I tried, but since, by itself, it doesn't return anything to screen, and since `?summary.nlmrt` says it returns an invisible copy of the `nlmrt` object, I didn't think it could return the stats I was looking for.